# How do you tell if the span of a set of vectors enters the most positive sector of a graph?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have $k$ linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  I want to know if the span of these vectors (i.e. the set of points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that can be described by linear combinations of these vectors) intersects the portion of $\mathbb{R}^n$ where all the axes are positive (e.g. the first quadrant in $\mathbb{R}^2$, the first octant in $\mathbb{R}^3$, etc.).

Is there a test I can run on my vectors that will answer this question?

Comment: Just a sidenote: the general term for quadrant, octant, etc. which applies for any $n$ is "orthant".

Answer (score 3):

In practice, the way to do this (where $n$ and $k$ may be large) is with linear programming software, since this is basically a linear programming feasibility problem: $A x \ge (1,\ldots, 1)^T$ where $A$ is the $n \times k$ matrix whose columns are your vectors.

Answer (score 2):

The magic words are "Farkas' Lemma".

Comment: The specific form of the question (where the cone is exactly the positive orthant) shows up in option-pricing models. In Ross's textbook, An Elementary Introduction to Mathematical Finance, the exact question is called the Arbitrage Theorem.